# Delete lots of rows from Cassandra Table

Tags: cassandra

I have a table Foo with 4 columns A, B, C, D, E.
The partition key is A.
The clustering key is B, C, D.

what I'd like to do?

> delete rows with specific partition keys

why I'd like to do that?

> to reclaim the storage

how I'd like to do that?

> use datastax/python-driver

I'd like these rows deleted with minimal disruption or risk.
I'm worried about the effect to read/write requests during deletion.
And I want to reclaim the storage ASSP, don't know how to deal with tombstone.

Answer (score 1):

Deletes in Cassandra are adding the data to the tables, not modifying the existing tables.  The reclaim of the disk space will happen during compaction process that will create new SSTable from the existing one, and removing the outdated or deleted data, so you'll need to have enough disk space to perform compaction of SSTables.  You can tune compaction properties, like, `min_threshold` to force compaction happen faster, or even do `nodetool compact -s` after deletion to force rewrite of the whole table.

Deletion of data using Python is [straightforward](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/getting_started/#prepared-statement) - just prepare a query like this

```
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE pk = ?;
```

and then iterate over your list of keys to delete, and call `session.execute(prepared_statement, [key_to_delete])`.